# how do i solve this problem of within class scatter matrix in LDA using python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, performance

This is the section of the code i used

```
SW = np.zeros((9,9))
    for i in range(1,9): #2 is number of classes
        per_class_sc_mat = np.zeros((9,9))
        for j in range(data[data["Class"]==i].shape[0]):
            row, mv = data.loc[j][:9].reshape(9,1), mean_vec[i]values.reshape(9,1)
    per_class_sc_mat += (row-mv).dot((row-mv).T)
    SW += per_class_sc_mat
    print('within-class Scatter Matrix:\n', SW)
    overall_mean = np.array(data.drop("lass", axis=1).mean())
```

showing these error

```
File "<ipython-input-23-89f983069500>", line 6
        row, mv = data.loc[j][:9].reshape(9,1), mean_vec[i]values.reshape(9,1)
                                                                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you forget a dot `mean_vec[i].values` ?

Comment: row, mv = data.loc[j][:9].reshape(9,1), mean_vec[i].reshape(9,1)